# TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition blinks

Tags: android, android-transitions

I'm trying to provide a fullscreen button for my camera view which is in my app. Unfortunately, during the transition, the app is showing newly calculated params before the actual animation. I mean, the new dimensions of camera view are seen for a while (blinks), then the screen is becoming black and in the end, the animation of expanding is done. This is how I do it:

```
        fullScreenBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isFullScreen){
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(transitionsContainer);
                fragmentContener.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                hudView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                mCameraContent.setLayoutParams(params);
                isFullScreen = false;
            } else {
                TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(transitionsContainer);
                fragmentContener.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                hudView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mCameraContent.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                isFullScreen = true;
            }
        }
```

The `fullScreenBtn` is in the `mCameraContent` layout on the camera preview in the corner. `transitionContainer` is the whole activity layout. I think it is worth noting that my activity layout is divided into two equal views: `baseContener` and `fragmentContener`, the `hudView` is inside the `baseContener`  below `mCameraContent`. They are fading out properly, the only problem is with camera preview. I was trying to add `Slide()` or `ChangeBounds()` into `beginDelayedTransition` method but that doesn't solve the problem. What should I do to avoid that view blinking?

Comment: Any luck here? I have this same problem. I think it has something to do with setting the view to `GONE`